# 2 possible outputs for 1 if statement python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am just figuring out the basics. I was just wondering how to have two possible choices in one if statement from one input.

```
   q2 = input("What is the capital of Brazil? ")
   if q2 == 'Brasilia' or 'brazilia':
        print("Correct!")

   else:
        print("Wrong! The answer was Brasilia.")
```

However this does not work as when you put in a wrong answer, it says that it is "Correct!"

Comment: Did you mean `brasilia` instead of `brazilia`?

Comment: Or perhaps `Brazilia`?

Comment: `q2 == 'Brasilia' or 'brazilia'` doesn't do what you're expecting. Can't find the duplicate but there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of getting the desired result here:

1. `if q2 == 'Brasilia' or q2 == 'brasilia':`
2. `if q2.lower() == 'brasilia':`
3. `if q2 in ('Brasilia', 'brasilia')`
4. `if q2.lower() in ('brasilia',)`

Option #1 is just a correction for what you have. If you have only one real option that is just case sensitive, option #2 is a simple way to go. If you have many options, #3 and #4 are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks very much! :)

Comment: @Stanley. No problem. Your question is a duplicate, but I can see how it would be hard to find the correct terms to ask it if you are a beginner. In this case, I found it quicker to answer than to mark as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

If capitalization is not important then you could do:

```
if q2.lower() == 'brazilia':
```

or, if only first letter can be like this then:

```
if q2[0].lower() == 'b' and q[1:] == 'razilia':
```

Also, if you have more *different* words that fit the answer then use Python's `in` statement to check if the world belongs to a list of possible choices:

```
if q2 in ['Brazilia', 'Brasilia']:
```

etc. You can combine `str.lower()` and/or `str.upper()` with `in` statement if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The`or` does not work like you're trying to use it; think of it as `bool(q2 == 'Brasilia') or bool('brasilia')`; `bool('brasilia')` is `True`, so it will always be true.

You would need to use "`q2 == 'Brasilia' or q2 == 'brasilia'`", although `q2.lower() == 'brasilia'` is more idiomatic and more forgiving, unless it is important that it be strict.